# I have a failing case when making an IDP connection using pingfederate

Tags: certificate, single-sign-on, saml, pingfederate, idp

The server.log says "signature_status": "UNVERIFIED". Is this a certificate issue?
Also what are the best ways to read the pingfederate logs in windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like an issue with signature verification, which could be the cert itself but is more likely a configuration issue. More information is really needed to know which it is.

I assume the issue you are having with reading logs on windows machines is because the files are large or are moving quickly. If the files are too big  you can modify the log4j2.xml config file at appdir/pingfed*/pingfed*/server/default/conf/log4j2.xml to reduce the log size to something easier to read in notepad. Here is an example rolling file appender that should leave you with easily maneageable files.

```
    <RollingFile name="FILE" fileName="${sys:pf.log.dir}/server.log"
                 filePattern="${sys:pf.log.dir}/server.log.%i" ignoreExceptions="false">
        <PatternLayout>
            <!-- Uncomment this if you want to use UTF-8 encoding instead
                of system's default encoding.
            <charset>UTF-8</charset> -->
            <pattern>%d %X{trackingid} %-5p [%c] %m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
                    size="20000 KB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
    </RollingFile>
```

If you issue is that the files are moving too fast to read then you might consider using something like [baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/) or Get-Content in powershell now that it has a tail switch.